# Iterating through OpenLayers 3 clusters in cluster source

Tags: openlayers-3

Using OpenLayers 3 (a JavaScript library I'm using to display objects on a map), I have a cluster source defined this way:

```
(...)
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
                distance: 20,
                source: vectorSource
            });
(...)
```

When I build a new feature I add it to vector source this way

```
vectorSource.addFeature(myFeature);
```

My request includes an additional property which is the object they are related to. Each of these objets have their own`id`.

```
myFeature.linkedObject = myObject;
```

Where `myObject.id` is the object's `id`.

**To say it in other words, I manage my objects and their features and let the "cluster source" manage and render clusters.**

What I need now is to be able to browe through existing clusters to find which one contains the object matching some `id`.

**How can I get a list/array of the currently existing clusters?**

Something equivalent to

```
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster(...);
**var clusters = clusterSource.getClusters();**
```

which by the way doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems that clusterSource.getFeatures(); will do it. Not sure yet, testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cluster sources have a getFeatures() function.

```
clusterSource.getFeatures();
```